# Изменение цвета текста у элемента в ListBox в зависимости от значения enum

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, color

Смысл таков, по мере работы программы, она добавляется новый элемент в коллекцию `Items`. Например если всё нормально - выводится сообщения с типом `Default`. Если возникла ошибка -  на экране в ListBox появлется новый элемент с красным текстом о том, что что-то не получилось. Если есть другие способы, то я не против их использовать. Т.е на экране будет своеобразная "радуга" из текста.

Есть Model:

```
class Model
{
    public enum State
    {
        Default = 0x000000, //black
        Success = 0x00FF00, //green
        Warning = 0xFFA500, //orange
        Error = 0xFF0000, //red
    }
    public State LogState { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Есть xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
     <local:StateToColorConverter x:Key="StateToColor"></local:StateToColorConverter>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- Не работает, а надо, чтобы работало -->
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Foreground="{Binding Items/LogState, Converter=StateToColor}"/>
```

Есть VM

```
class ViewModel
{
    
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Items {get; set;}

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        Items.Add(new Model { LogState = Model.State.Error, Message = "Ошибка" });
    }
}
```

Так же реализовал `IValueConverter`, но как его применить через `<Window.Resources>` коллекции не знаю.

```
class StateToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Model.State status = (Model.State)value;
        var color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        switch (status)
        {
            case Model.State.Error:
                    color = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
                    break;
            case Model.State.Success:
                    color = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0));
                    break;

        }

        return color;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Запомните одно простое правило: MVVM, это про слои, где каждый слой мало чего знает про другой слой. Model - это данные, то есть тот слой, где вы получаете данные с сайта/базы/файла/устройства и др. View - это UI, все цвета, стили, кнопочки, шрифты, эффекты, анимации, др. Тут вы не должны вообще чего-либо знать про VM и M слои, лишь привязаться к абстракции. ViewModel - это связующий слой, где берутся данные из М, делаются свойства для привязки, ну и обрабатываются команды, все. В нем не должно быть указание цвета контролу, либо вовсе `MyTextBox.Text = "привет мир!"`, это нарушение.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в теории-то понятно, а вот на практике уже совсем другое дело. К слову, бизнес-логика - это тоже Model?

Comment: Просто помните про слои, задавайте себе всегда вопрос "а это точно должно быть здесь?", не забываем еще про SRP. Вот у вас цвет в Model слое (`Success = 0x00FF00`), вот задав вопрос, какой ответ получите? Наверно нет, ибо данный цвет вам нужен только в UI, так почему это прописано в логике? Не ясно... `Model` - как и сказал выше, это все данные, вся работа с ними. Делаете вы калькулятор, там методы суммирования, умножения и т.д. - это Model. Пишете парсер сайта, вся логика по работе с его API - Model. Работа с базой - Model. ну и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте вложенные типы. Не нужно в Enum зашивать цвета, за это должна не модель отвечать, а UI

```cs
public enum Severity
{
    Default,
    Success,
    Warning,
    Error
}

public class LogMessage
{
    public Severity Severity { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Использовать это точно так же

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<LogMessage> Items { get; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<LogMessage>();
        Items.Add(new LogMessage { Severity = Severity.Error, Message = "Ошибка" });
    }
}
```

А все фокусы с раскрашиванием реализуются в UI XAML. Кстати, зачем вам `ListBox` вы выбирать сообщение хотите или только смотреть?

```xml
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity}" Value="Success">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity}" Value="Warning">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity}" Value="Error">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Всё. Никаких конвертеров не нужно.

Comment: Как работает xaml у Вас? Я не могу указать `TextBlock` в `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`. Однако, если указать `DataTemplate` после `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`, то всё нормально. `ListBox` первый пришел на ум, его и использовал для вывода списка

Comment: @Aarnihauta да, писал по памяти прямо здесь без студии, забыл про `DataTemplate`. Исправил.